# Flag declined but answer deleted for same reason

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Normally I accept that some flags I raise will be declined, attempt to learn from them and just continue reviewing, but I need to understand this one. I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22180166) as not an answer (as it is nothing more than a suggestion with no evidence to justify why it might work), and it was

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

However the post has since been deleted from review, with the only comment from review on the post being the stock "This does not provide an answer to the question...", which is exactly the reason I flagged it to begin with.

Can someone explain to me the reasoning behind the flag being declined?

For non-10k rep users, this was the answer:

> try `set LANG=en_US.utf-8` before start screen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your original "not an answer" flag was declined by a moderator. The message you quoted is one of the canned messages we have to choose from when declining a flag.

The same post was later deleted by community members through the "Low Quality Posts" review queue, which is what you see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22180166). The *"This does not provide an answer to the question..."* comment that you see posted there was automatically posted by a user in from the review queue, where it is one of the canned messages that reviewers have to choose from.

Community members don't always adhere to the rules as strictly as moderators do. In some ways, that's good. Community members who are experts in a particular topic can use that expertise to judge whether an answer is completely useless and thus a candidate for deletion. Moderators in general are not able to do this, because we are not experts in every technology covered by Stack Overflow. In other ways, that's bad, because community members are a lot less accountable for their actions than moderators (although, to some extent, that is compensated for by the weight of the votes).

> I flagged this answer as not an answer (as it is nothing more than a suggestion with no evidence to justify why it might work) [...]

That is not the criteria for a "not an answer" flag. A suggestion that is conceivably relevant to the question *is* an answer. It might not be a *correct* answer (which is what the declined flag message is driving at), and it might not be a particularly *high-quality* answer (which is addressed by the downvote button), but it *is* an answer by [our standards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer), and you risk having your flag declined if you flag it as not being one.

In this case, the question was *"How to make GNU screen recognize UTF-8 characters"*, and the answer was *"try `set LANG=en_US.utf-8` before start screen"*. It isn't particularly well-written, but it does pass the basic litmus test. It is an attempt to provide an answer, and it appears to be related to the question. It is conceivable that setting a `LANG` setting to `en_US.utf-8` would make GNU screen able to recognize/display UTF-8 characters. Moderators do not render judgments beyond that. In particular, we do not assess the technical accuracy of answers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I appreciate you taking the time.